# How to Rename XML Elements Using XSLT with Existing Template

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I want to change the element name from "NAME" to "CD-NAME" in my XML file, but my XSLT says I can't place a template inside another template ("Element xsl:template must be top-level"). How can I change the tag name if a template already exists?

XML (input):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <NAME>Empire Burlesque</NAME>
    </CD>
```

XSLT (What I tried):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="/CD">
        <xsl:variable name="id"
            select="*[contains(local-name(), 'NAME')]"/>
        <CD>
            <info>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$id" copy-namespaces="no"/>
                <xsl:template match="CD/NAME">
                    <CD-NAME><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></CD-NAME>
                </xsl:template> 
            </info>
        </CD>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML (What I want):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CD>
   <info>
      <CD-NAME>Empire Burlesque</CD-NAME>
   </info>
</CD>
```

Comment: Your example is ambiguous: it is not clear whether `info` should appear only once (as a sub-element of `CD`) or for every occurrence of `NAME`. --- P.S. There are no "tags" in XSLT; the correct term is ""element".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
  <! Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CD">
    <xsl:copy>                     <!-- Copies the "CD" element -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />  <!-- Copies the attributes of the "CD" element -->
      <info>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </info>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CD/NAME">
    <CD-NAME><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></CD-NAME>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output should be as desired.

Answer (score 0):

As already noticed in the comments, your example is not clear. The expected result could be produced by either:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/CD">
    <CD>
        <info>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </info>
    </CD>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NAME">
    <CD-NAME>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </CD-NAME>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/CD">
    <CD>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </CD>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NAME">
    <info>
        <CD-NAME>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </CD-NAME>
    </info>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If there is only one `NAME` element, then the result will be the same in both cases. But if there always will be only one `NAME` element, then all you need to do is just this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/CD">
    <CD>
        <info>
            <CD-NAME>
                <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
            </CD-NAME>
        </info>
    </CD>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```